# How is the tag chosen to prefix the title?

Tags: support, tags, title

Which tag is used in the title of a question?

- It does not seem to be the most popular
- It does not seem to be the first in the tagging order:

This question
[Loopback connection via PHP's getimage size crashes server (Magento's CMS)](https://serverfault.com/questions/441051/loopback-connection-via-phps-getimage-size-crashes-server-magentos-cms)

is prefixed with NGINX (which is actually completely fine)

And it is tagged with "php nginx fastcgi magento" in the order of popularity.

Can we choose the tag to use in the title manually?

Comment: Related (and perhaps a dupe given the answer): [Why is the first tag sometimes in the <title> tag of some questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's the most popular tag that doesn't already appear in the title.

In your example, PHP is mentioned in the title so the second-most popular tag "nginx" is chosen for the HTML title.

Comment: What happens if second most popular tag is also present in title? It doesn't show anything?