# What determines which tag(s) are shown on the webpage title?

Tags: support, tags, window-title

How is it determined which tags are shown at the start of the question in the title of the webpage?

[This is related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153455/how-is-the-tag-chosen-to-prefix-the-title) however the answer is incorrect as proved by [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/245132/106901) which has no tag in the title despite "backwards compatibility" not being used in the question. Also by [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245177/how-can-i-tell-who-owns-a-ready-to-install-game) which has two tags. [This question is similar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245115/how-does-blur-stack-with-resistances), it has two tags similarly named to the previous one but only one tag is shown in the title of this one. Why is this?

So what determines how many tags are shown and which tags or why are no tags shown?

Note this question **may** be only applicable to arqade.

Comment: Arqade's title tagging seems to be completely messed up, probably because it's had some customizations applied. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149166/can-an-xbox-one-player-party-or-voice-chat-with-an-xbox-360-player has a tag in the title that is *not in its tag list*.

Comment: @NathanTuggy not for me, that question you linked has no tags in title for me

Comment: Odd. For me, it shows "Chat - ", but I've never visited that question before.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the most popular tag of all the tags on the question (i.e. The tag on the left-most side). For example, on this question, the tag would be [discussion], but some sites don't have it, or that algorithm may vary by site.

Comment: @Zizouz212 yes according to the linked question, it should be the most popular tag that doesn't appear in the title, that doesn't explain why there are sometimes two tags, and sometimes no tags (when the tag hasn't been mentioned in the title)

Comment: Sounds like a bug, but it sounds unique to Gaming. You should probably raise this on the Gaming meta.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I spend the most time on arqade so noticed it there, I thought it'd have been the same on other sites too. Maybe some people can mention if it's the same on other sites.

Comment: Well, you've now got an answer from our awesome overlords :D

Answer (score 5):

> This is related however the answer is incorrect as proved by this question which has no tag in the title despite "backwards compatibility" not being used in the question.

Both [xbox-360] and [xbox-one] are more popular than [backwards-compatibility] and both are present in the title. (We replace hyphens with spaces when we do this check.) We don't add another tag at that point - 2 is the max for Arqade, the default network-wide is 1.

> This question is similar, it has two tags similarly named to the previous one but only one tag is shown in the title of this one. Why is this?

The goal here is to include tags for SEO purposes. There's no benefit from doing a title like `diablo 3 diablo 3 wizard - ...`. We de-dupe tags to only include overlapping terms once.

Comment: It seems like everyone's getting different results. No tags are appearing in that question for me: http://i.imgur.com/sUugjKP.png and see Nathan's comment where an unrelated tag is appearing in the title

Comment: @Aequitas I can't repro what Nathan is seeing either. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Whatever it is, sounds like a bug that should be reported separately by the person who actually ran into it.

Comment: how does the system know that xbox 360 and xbox one tags are both useful, whereas diablo 3 isn't useful if diablo 3 wizard is already there?

Comment: @Aequitas The check for duplicate info only runs if the tags aren't already present in the title. Since the title is "Can I play against or with Xbox 360 players through my Xbox One?", we just stop there. The other question doesn't mention "diablo 3" in the title at all, so we go through all tags and remove ones that are full subsets of other tags (so "diablo 3 wizard" wins).

Comment: oh sorry now I understand, even if it's part of the question it still counts as one of those two tags.