# Does the <title> prefix from a post tag, that SE renders in post HTML, affect post placement or visibility?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, title

I asked [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/255882/125972) and noticed that it was <title>'ed as *"**drywall** - How should you insulate ..."*

Primarily the question is about insulation, however: the question does mention drywall, and drywall is relevant to the question so both "insulation" and "drywall" are listed as tags ...but it would make more sense if the <title> was *"**insulation** - How should you insulate ..."*

[This meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153457/801099) points out that the prefix in the title is *"the most popular tag that doesn't already appear in the title."*

**Meta Question:**

Does this <title> prefix (ie, "drywall -") indicate some kind of placement, prioritization, categorization, or otherwise affect visibility to other potential answer writers (users) within SE?

- If so: then it would be nice to have control of the tag.
- If not: ok, then is it just SEO sugar?

Comment: The prefix comes from the question's _tags_ sorted by popularity (ref. [How is the tag chosen to prefix the title?](/q/153455/1099857)). With ~1.9k questions [drywall] is more popular than [insulation] (at ~1.6k questions), so that is the tag which is used in the title.

Comment: Your question is a bit split. If the question is "how are the tags chosen to prefix the title," it's a duplicate of the above linked Q & A. If this is meant to be a feature request, then it would be helpful to expand upon that part to include some more details about _why_ this would be beneficial and _what_ the tag change process might look like.

Comment: Do you only want to change it for this particular question? Be able to override the decision for individual questions? If not, what should a new general rule be? Manually set the priority between various tags? E.g., tag X always overrides tag Y? Or tag X gets a 77% higher weight (as an example)? Or some other rule(s)?

Comment: By "Can it be changed?" do you mean changed for you personally in your browser (e.g. with a userscript; "yes") or do you mean for all users ("no")? Do you mean "is there a way that we can specify which tag to use for that while keeping all the current tags?" ("no") Something else? Please [edit] to clarify what you are intending.

Comment: @HenryEcker, updated question.  btw, do I have to tell you (and others?) the question was updated or will it notify you and everyone else who commented?

Comment: @KJ7LNW it won't notify people, but most active people see that its up again in the active sort of the question list, as it was edited. But if you addressed a persons specific concern it can't harm to @-mention them in a comment.

Comment: As for the why this happens: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72076/361484