# The single-use-tag deletion script will no longer be turned off on any new sites. Will it be turned back on at sites where it is currently off?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

It used to be the case that any tag that was 6 months old and had only been applied to a single question would be deleted. [This was a bad idea on many beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153357/224428), and so the script that did the deleting was selectively deactivated on some sites, including at least Arqade, Anime.SE, and SF&F.

[According to a recent post by an employee](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1158/6260), this script will not be deactivated on any further sites; the endorsed solution is to create a tag wiki for any tag that ought to be preserved, since tags that have wikis are only deleted if there are *zero* questions with that tag.

My question: are there any plans to turn the deletion script *back on* on the sites where it is currently off?

Comment: I hope not. I've yet to see any good coming out of single-use tag deletion. I've seen it cause plenty of harm, on pretty much every site where I've had an occasion to check, including SO. Doing irreversible, unlogged deletions is crazy.

Comment: @Gilles Agreed. I spent some time a little while back looking at [untagged] questions on various sites; [the carnage was particularly bad](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) at [boardgames.se].