# "Bumped to the homepage by Community" after suggested edit approved by Community

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, community-user, bump

It looks like there's a new message shown when Community bumps inactive questions:

> #### Bumped to the homepage by Community 10 hours ago
>
> This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.

But on Japanese.SE, this message is showing up on a question that's only 21 hours old, [after a suggested edit was approved by a moderator](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41243/conditional-sentence-translation), which doesn't seem like the right behavior to me.

I imagine this message was intended to be shown whenever a question is bumped to the top of the front page after being inactive for some time.  That didn't happen here,  so the message appearing on this question seems like unintended behavior.

---

Screen shots showing the current state of the question:

> [image: screen shot of bump message]
>
> [image: screen shot of revision history page]

Comment: Who approved the edit? Was it the OP?

Comment: @ChrisF It was approved by a moderator.

Comment: I'm looking at the active questions list for these bumps and just made another observation: That message is not shown at all for "real" community bumps. Only for anonymous (community) edits. Reversed logic somewhere?

Comment: This is a brand new feature that didn't get implemented quite correctly. Devs will take care of it. :)

Comment: Related: [How can we make the purpose of Community "bumping" more obvious?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279203/how-can-we-make-the-purpose-of-community-bumping-more-obvious)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've updated the code path that displays the message to actually check that a question has been community bumped, before showing it.

With you in the next build.

Comment: Now I can't find the message on any question, even if it's been bumped by Community.  For example http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148300/ and http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/105404/ were bumped by Community, but there's no message.

Comment: That's by design. The message ages away. Configured for 3 days most sites.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Within fifteen minutes?  [The ELL post was bumped at 10:20](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/105404/timeline), and I was looking at it before I posted my comments 14 minutes later and never saw the message.  EDIT: Oh, three days?  Well, it should still be visible on the ELL post now then, right?

Comment: Should be 3 days, not minutes, yeah. Will have to look at it - could be that the test to see if the post was eligible for a bump which happens before checking for an actual bump is faulty (logically, that is).

Comment: @snailplane - issues was that I was testing against the wrong database fields... I have pushed a fix that will be available in the next build (one note - the message will disappear if any subsequent activity happens on the post - such as an edit).

Comment: Has Community lost its diamond, then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - it will get it back in the next build.

Answer (score 0):

As Animuson stated, the bump message should not been shown, as it is a work-in-progress feature that did come through on production:

> This is a brand new feature that didn't get implemented quite correctly. Devs will take care of it. :)

For the edit: it was not approved by Community, it was approved by a moderator on the site, but was suggested by an anonymous user. All edits by anonymous users are attributed to Community. I hope that clears your confusion on this.