# "Bumped to the homepage" notices should link to Community ♦ user's profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, community-user, bump

So we apparently have some nice new "Bumped to the homepage" notices that are attached to questions that are bumped by Community ♦. Nice.

> [image]

All other notices attributed to Community ♦ link to said user's profile:

> [image]
>
> [image]

This new notice however does not:

> [image]

Should it? I'd possibly argue that it doesn't need to attribute the bumping to Community ♦ at all, but if it does it should probably link to the profile;

1. for consistency, and
2. to explain to newer users what this weird non-user actually is.

The notice is also missing the absolute time tooltip that you get when hovering over the relative time on other notices. And more generally, the entire line is bold where for consistency with other notices, only "Bumped to the homepage" should be bold.

Comment: Well, it had a [bumpy start](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287445/bumped-to-the-homepage-by-community-after-suggested-edit-approved-by-community)... ;-)

Comment: @Sha I did see that. Community lost its ♦ for a bit there too :)

Comment: Also missing the tooltip with absolute time, which exists in all timestamps around SE.

Comment: Anyone else bothered by the fact that this is the only post notice that starts with a capital letter now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, mostly my fault - given this is a (mostly) static notice (always community, only thing that changes in the date).

I've:

- Lowercased the starting b
- Removed the bold formatting from "by" to the end of the sentence
- Gave community its link back
- Ensured the date has a hover

With you in next build.

Comment: It would be nice to have an announcing meta post that specifies how this behaviour works in detail. Does the notice stick with the post? Does it go away? If so, how? What happens if a post is bumped twice? (This [does](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6276) happen.) What happens if e.g. a bounty is added, or the post is closed?

Comment: Only the latest bump is used, the bump ages away (3 days by default). If a post gets any activity after the bump, the message goes away (as the bump is now due to the new activity).